# o'reilly adds extra path. Why?

Tags: file-upload, multipartform-data

Here is my code to set upload path:

```
    FileManager fm  = new FileManager();
    String srcPath  = fm.directoryPath("ownOIPath");

    MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(req, srcPath,
    50 *90000 * 90000, new com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.DefaultFileRenamePolicy());
```

"srcPath" is read from *.properties file.

Path I provided in properties file is:

ownOIPath = /var/www/vhosts/globalsteelweb.com/httpdocs/UploadedFiles/ownOI/

I changed this path and set in windows environment then its working fine 
but **why its (adding /var/java/aache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/gsw)** extra on the linux server:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a directory: 
**/var/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/gsw/var**/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/UploadedFiles/ownOI

Please advise

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked everything but that was really strange fix. At the end of the path that I written in my properties file there was a white space. When I removed it everything started to work perfectly